# Function doesn't run in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I use a sample code to find a string in main string. But when I run it on editor online, it work fine. But when I run it in local host XAMPP, it doesn't work.

I try to comment all and just only alert(), it work. But when I run default code, it return nothing.

The main problem in here is that, when I run it in online editor like w3schools, it can work and return the results fine. But when I run it on my machine (I use XAMPP), it totally return nothing.

This is my code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to extract characters from the string.</p>
<button onclick="findNewProgrammingLanguage()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function findNewProgrammingLanguage() {
        var programminglanguages = "C++, JavaScript, Ruby";
        var newlanguage = "Python";
        if (programminglanguages.indexOf(newlanguage) >=0) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = language;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FO6C714HYD7C

Comment: Without any information of use, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: I gave my code in the link in question above.

Comment: Please edit your question and post relevant code for us to see. Thank you.

Comment: Var **language** is always unknown. Besides that, your **if** will always be false cause **Python** isn't inside **programminglanguages**.

Comment: I actually make this mistake. I want to show to result in else condition. But instead return "no" in screen, it still return nothing!

Comment: Returns "no" because your **if** will always be false cause **Python** isn't one of the options showed in **programminglanguages**.

Comment: @statosdotcom you don't understand my word. I say even it false, it still not return "no" to my screen. My web still blank and get no result!

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: I see now, excuse me. Maybe your browser has restrictions to run local javascript. Anyway you could use browser console to check what's happening with your code.

Comment: When I try to use console to debug, it work fine. The result show in console.

Comment: Maybe your browser is set to show "friendly" error messages... (besides it's not an error...) and in the particular case he is timid to say "no"  :D Seriously, it seems a browser matter, or it is a local js restriction or.... Have you tried another browser?

Comment: This is debug in console in my machine. https://imgur.com/a/EPIrd

Comment: I also use another browser, but still get nothing for that.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if statement, which is the value of `language`?

```
if (programminglanguages.indexOf(newlanguage) >=0) {   
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = language; // language is not defined
}
```

I think that's the problem

Comment: I actually make this mistake. I want to show to result in else condition. But instead return "no" in screen, it still return nothing!

Comment: @statosdotcom Teaching strategies ;)

Comment: It still not return anything in my web screen.

Comment: In that case, @Sae, it seems that something is happening with your XAMPP configuration, because I just made this in a pen and it prints the "No" -> https://codepen.io/ddazal/pen/QQNZgP. Better, open your console and check what is happening

Comment: OP (original post) already says (actually two times) when online the code works normally. Besides that, if it was a matter of XAMPP configuration, the alert - again mentioned in OP, would not work too.

Comment: @statosdotcom you right. When I try to disable all code inside function and replace it with only alert("hello, world"); then it run fine in my machine. I don't know why...

Comment: @Sae Have you tried to run it without XAMPP? Just opening yout HTML file in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can solved what problem here. It have some confusing with config file in XAMPP. I try to turn off it and restart. And then it work!